# Pyramid authorization based on client IP address

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

I successfully setup authentication and user based authorization following the [pyramid documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/authorization.html).

Now I want to disable this authorization if the side is accessed from localhost. How can I make my authorization depending on the client `IP` address, i.e. localhost?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways by which you can get the client side IP address. 
Using [remote_addr](https://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/1.0-branch/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.remote_addr) or you can use  [client_addr](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.client_addr).

Comment: Thanks. But how can I include this in the authorization? How do I add this to the ACLAuthorizationPolicy? Or do I need to derive my own authorization policy class?